# php sending get request to get info

Tags: php, nginx, serialization, get, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send from a php code running on a nginx server a get request to another remote django server. I am expecting to get data in REST API using serializer.

First if I open this link in my local browser:

> http://192.168.2.0:8000/myapp/documents/

I will get:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": "000e3588-9544-4df6-a589-cc0166242b5b",
        "docfile": "/media/documents/2017/06/30/DSC03623.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": "3dc6be9f-8659-41d8-8282-b64662032da6",
        "docfile": "/media/documents/2017/06/30/DSC03611_9KWbftQ.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": "28eacb2d-0798-46e9-b63e-10ff704482ce",
        "docfile": "/media/documents/2017/06/30/DSC03555.JPG"
    }
]
```

and this is exactly the info I want to get when i run my php code.

This is what I was working on, the commented parts are previous failed attempts:

```
<?php
   echo "<h1>I am here</h1>";
   $url = "http://192.168.2.0:8000/myapp";

   /*$body = http_parse_message(http_get($url))->body;
   $body = http_get($url);
   echo $body;*/

   /*$client = new Client($url);
   $request = $client->newRequest('/documents/');
   $response = $request->getResponse();
   echo $response->getParsedResponse();*/

   $r = new HttpRequest('http://192.168.2.0:8000/myapp/documents/', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
   $r->send();
   echo $r->getResponseCode();
   if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) 
   {       
           echo "<h2>we get 200 response</h2>";
   }       

?>
```

non of the above 3 attempts printed anything except the first echo

> ## I am here

Comment: Well start by adding an ELSE to your if like `} else { echo 'actual response= ' . $r->getResponseCode(); }` and see what you do get back

Comment: I added it and nothing is shown.
why i did not add an else statement int the first place is because I am monitoring the django server on the other PC. When I run the php code no request is reaching django. As if no http connection is created

Comment: Well then tell us what you see being reported on the other server

Comment: nothing... when i run this link (http://192.168.2.0:8000/myapp/documents/) in a browser on the php server side, i can see on the django side something like that:
********[03/Jul/2017 10:48:17] "GET /myapp/documents/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7079
[03/Jul/2017 10:48:17] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[03/Jul/2017 10:48:17] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
....

[03/Jul/2017 11:35:16] "GET /myapp/documents/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7079 *******   

running the php code will not show anything

Comment: Then you need to show us the code that you think is being run on the django server

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally this is the code that worked for me:

```
<?php
   $ch = curl_init('http://192.168.2.0:8000/myapp/documents/');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $data;
?>
```

it needs cUrl to work.
cUrl usual enabled in php. To double check
run this code as a script:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

search in in the results if cUrl is working.